# Path finding in time dependent graphs and murderous hitchhikers

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow, network

Last week I heard some informatic students talking about car-to-car communication via wifi-hotspots in cars and the following problem occured to me:

Suppose you are making a road trip with many friends and multiple cars and for some reason, all cars in the world are equipped with their own local wifi-hotspot. Obviously you don't want to call your friends in the other cars using cellphones (too expensive). Being a group of nerdy computer scientists, you wrote a chat application that uses the wifi-hotspots from cars in your neighbourhood to communicate for free!

All is well untill the dumb friend decides to pick up a shady looking hitchhiker armed with several blood-spattered axes. Anyway, as the distance between your cars grows larger, you lose a direct communication path. How do you establish and maintain communication with your friends' car using only the local wifi-hotspots of all cars?

Let's state this problem in a more mathematical language: Suppose you are given a time dependent (directed) graph and every vertex only has local information on this graph (it only sees close neighbours). Suppose you are riding on some vertex $A$ and you want to send a message to vertex $B$ but you don't know where vertex $B$ is.

Can you, under reasonable assumptions, find vertex $B$ and communicate with it? Preferably you try to keep said communication channel alive as long as possible. If so, what is a reasonable algorithm or idea to do this?

Also, is there any reasonable variant of this problem that can be "solved" using some interesting tools from linear algebra (such as eigenvectors)?

Perhaps I should point out that [the following paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.377.329&rep=rep1&type=pdf) seems related but is not really what I hoped for. I'm more interested in basic linear algebra or elementary ideas that can help to tackle such problems. I'm not very interested in the technical implementation of such algorithms and their complexity.

Comment: I think if you don't know anything about the graph, your best bet is to send your message out to all vertices you can see and tell each of them to also send it out to everyone they can see. This way your message will go to every vertex in the graph and so eventually reach your friend. Unfortunately this is terribly inefficient and if your friend is not reachable from you, you won't even know about it.

Comment: @quarague: Perhaps one should assume that $A$ and $B$ start at roughly the same localization. Once you lose car $B$, you at least have some general sense of direction of where $B$ was and you can search more directly. I was hoping one could exploit information of the (also time-dependent) adjacency graph.

Comment: If you want to have a sense of direction, you assume your graph to be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^2$ I guess? Furthermore, you would need to get and send real life locations with all messages, and also specify that your message should only be forwarded in a certain geographical area. However, this is not a mathematical solution. From a pure mathematical/linear algebra standpoint, I agree with @quarague that broadcasting to everyone would be your best bet.